# Extract Text from multi-line string

Tags: java, android, regex

I've one string MYSTRING with multiple lines as below:

`X:String1;;;;
X1:String2
X2:String3
YY1:String4`

My target is to extract each string from the above string. I found below formula:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\n|;|:](X:|X1:)[0-9a-zA-Z-\\säöüÄÖÜß,]*[\\n|;])");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(MYSTRING);

if(m.find())  {
    String  name = m.group(1).substring(1);
}
```

With the above forumla I succeeded to get String1 only.
how to get rest of String2, String3, .....?

Comment: Change `if` to `while` to iterate over all matching text. But your regex doesn't look right. For instance something like `[a|b]` will represent and match sing `a` OR `|` or `b`. Pipe (`|`) doesn't have any special meaning (it is NOT `or` operator) inside `[..]`.

Comment: As I mentioned, I succeeded to match the first sting only.which is X, but I can't match X1, or X2 or YY1

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/giG509 ?

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned earlier your regex would also accept characters which you didn't expect. For instance `[...(X:|X1:)...]` would accept `(` or `X` or `:` or `|` or `X` (this is not needed because character class already contains X) `:` (same problem as `X`, it is not needed again) and `)`. So let me repeat: character class allows us to match *single* character from a set of characters, so `[abc]` wouldn't match whole `abc` but `a` or `b` or `c`, regardless of their order.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by double matching queries as below:

First perform the query for X

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\n|;|:](X:)[0-9a-zA-Z-\\säöüÄÖÜß,]*[\\n|;])");
            m = pattern.matcher(MYSTRING);

        if(m.find())  {
            String  string1 = m.group(1).substring(1);
        }
```

Then perform the query for X1:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\n|;|:](X1:)[0-9a-zA-Z-\\säöüÄÖÜß,]*[\\n|;])");
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(MYSTRING);

        if(m.find())  {
            String  string2 = m.group(1).substring(1);
        }
```

This is not the right way specially if you have lot of fields, but at least it working for me just do query two times only, can be considered as temp sol.